# ASP.NET Core Web API calls 3rd Party API fails sometime with "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, azure-appservice

ASP.NET Core Web API is deployed in Azure App Service.

There is an endpoint that call 3rd party API which fails sometimes and all other request success.

The exception say

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (test-xyz-abc.org:19443)

I tried named `HttpClinet`, static `HttpClient` and `IHttpClientFactory`.

If I call the 3rd party API from Postman with several iteration, it works.

The problem comes only when it is called from Web API. Could this be request timeout of the `HttpClient` / `IHttpClientFactory` or the API which calls 3rd party need to be increased?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you able to produce the same issue locally? For testing purposes, if you are using the URL as a string then try to convert it to URI. `Uri myUri = new Uri(URLInStringFormat, UriKind.Absolute); WebClient client = new WebClient(); client.OpenRead(myUri);` Further, is there any proxy involved? or have you configured any proxy settings in the web.config? Also, try to check whether firewall causing the issue.

Comment: I tried with URI and used IHttpClientFactory. it is not working. is webclient nuget exist in c#?

Comment: If you are using Azure Virtual Network NAT gateway then whitelist the static IP addresses on the web service firewall. See whether it helps to fix the said issue.

Comment: it worked when I use the httpclient class as static readonly  as given below.        private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new SocketsHttpHandler
        {
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
            PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
            MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10
        });

Comment: Thanks for updating us with the solution to the issue. I would suggest you post your solution as an answer to this question may help other community members in the future with similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.